# How to update database value by checking textbox value in ajax or php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

```
<?php
    include('db_connect.php');

    $id = $_GET["id"];

    if(isset($_POST['name']))
    {
        $name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM brands WHERE name = '$name'",$link);
        $row =  mysql_num_rows($query);

    if($row==0)
    {
        echo 
        "
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            $('#logo').animate({marginLeft:'20px'},100);
            $('#logo').animate({marginLeft:'0px'},100);
        </script>
        ";
    }
    else
    {
        $database = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM brands",$link);
        $logo = $_POST['name'];
        $logo_n = $row["name"];

        if ($logo == $logo_n || $logo == strtolower($logo_n) || $logo == strtoupper($logo_n)) {

            mysql_query("UPDATE brands SET level_br = '$id' WHERE id = $id",$link);
        }
        else {
            echo "<script>alert('NO');</script>";
            echo "<script>console.log('NO');</script>";
        }
    }
    }
?>
```

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Comment: It looks like you are asking us to write you an *introduction to Ajax* tutorial. There are plenty out there already. Try Google.

Comment: I use ajax but db updating by reloading the page

Comment: first of all, your code is really really messy, mixing php and html is always a bad idea, you add javascript on the top !

Comment: Please give me one example Fredic Nault

Comment: ok Ill write a answer

Comment: Write an explanation of the problem as well as specific question(s). We don't know what is or isn't working so far or what problems you are having

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax will allow you to use a php script via javascript without having to reload the page

let say you have 3 files :

**application.js**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // add the click event to the checkbox
        $('#TheCheckbox').click(function() {

            // Looking if your checkox is checked  
            var Am_I_Checked = !$(this).is(':checked')

           // Use javascrip to send an ajax call to your php file
           var remoteFile = 'www.yourdomain.com/db_update.php';

           // Data to send to your php file, The php file will see
           // those vas in the $_GET array ...
           // This is json format use all the time in javascript if you need more info
           // google it :) .
           // http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_intro.asp
           var dataToSend = {
                'Am_I_Checked' : Am_I_Checked,
                'variable1'    : 'the value',
                'variable2'    : 'the value'
                // etc...   
           }

           // This is the fonction that will be executed once the php call is done
           // I know its look like a variable, but its a lamba style function, that
           // also exist in php is you dont know
           //
           // If you notice, the data parameter is what will be return by php ( echoed by ...)
           // In this example that will be recognize as json
           var oneAjaxIsDone = function(data) {
               //example
               alert(data.whatever); // in this example, that will alert the string : "you want to return"
           }

            $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                url: remoteFile,  /* the remote script to call */
                data: dataToSend, /* the json data of element that you want to send to your script */
                success: oneAjaxIsDone /*  there you pass your lamba */
                });

        })
    })
```

**index.html**

```
    <html>
        <header>
            <script src="jquery.js">
            <script src="application.js">
        </header>
        <body>
            <input id="TheCheckbox" type="checkbox">
        </body>
    </html>
```

**db_update.php**

```
    <?php
        $ajaxVars = $_GET[];

        // Do your database stuff .....

        // Now we will build the return, remeber the ajaxIsDone function above...
        $return = array('whatever' => 'you want to return');

        // When you send data from javascript to php via ajax that was in json format
        // we have to do the sameting here
        $jsonString = json_encode($return);

        echo $jsonString;
    ?>
```

To reiterate Do not ask you if you use ajax or php, because they do not do the same job

php : update your db, return answer

html : containe you html and layout

javascript : bing event to your checkbox object and trigger ajax

ajax : for know just see it as the taxi driver between your pate and your server script